# .net core replace update dll live

Tags: .net-core

I have the following solution structure:

Host references:

Project A

Project B (A requires B)

Project C

We are building a .net core solution using "dotnet publish -p:FileVersion=2.0.0.0"

After deploying, we sometime need to replace a dll file for bug fixing, we don't want to replace the entire solution (Project B & C) only the changed dll file (Project A)

Once we rebuild using "dotnet publish -p:FileVersion=2.1.0.0"
and try to replace only the dll of project A, we get the following error

Unhandled exception caught System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'ProjectB, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Using dotPeek I saw that both in .net core and in .net framework project A had a reference to project b with the new version 2.1.0.0

However in .net framework for same reason it didn't enforce the version check so project b was loaded successfully even when it was on 2.0.0.0

Any suggestions on how can I allow this in .net core (3.1) as well?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide some more structure reference? In Project A, if you have added reference of B and C . Now you build project A with version 2.0.0.0. Later stage you want to change only B's dll with newer version. You get above error . Right ?

Comment: Not exactly, I have host project (console) which has two direct project references A and C. later I change project A (without changing the project B). I'm rebuilding the entire host project and when I replace only project A dll, I get this error. hope this clarify it